# MongoDB : how to set joined table fields to null if there are no matching records found in joined table

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I've a table `tasks` which has following schema

```
id, name, type, points
```

Tasks can be assigned to users, so i'm saving those details in `user_tasks` table

```
id, user_id, task_id, status, completed_at, started_at
```

The aggregation will look like this

```
[
    {
        '$match': {
            'topic_id': new ObjectId('....'),
            'status': 'active'
        }
    }, {
        '$lookup': {
            'from': 'user_tasks',
            'localField': '_id',
            'foreignField': 'task_id',
            'as': 'started',
            'pipeline': [
                {
                    '$match': {
                        'user_id': new ObjectId('....')
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }, {
        '$unwind': {
            'path': '$started',
            'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true
        }
    }, {
        '$project': {
            'name': 1,
            'type': 1,
            'cur_task_status': '$started.status',
            'completed_at': '$started.completed_at',
            'started_at': '$started.started_at',
            'experience': 1
        }
    }
]
```

After the aggregation I got the following result

```
_id: ....
name: "Task Name"
points: 100
cur_task_status: "pending"
completed_at: ...
started_at: ...
```

For few records I can't see `cur_task_status, started_at, completed_at` fields, because there is no matching records in joined table, how can I add those missing fields with null values to the final result even if joined table doesn't have records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [$ifNull](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/)

```
  {
    $project: {
      "name": 1,
      "type": 1,
      "cur_task_status": {
        $ifNull: ["$started.status",null]
      },
      "completed_at": {
        $ifNull: ["$started.completed_at",null]
      },
      "started_at": {
        $ifNull: ["$started.started_at",null]
      },
      "experience": 1
    }
  }
```